# Changing chrome extension popup page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to load a different popup page based on some conditions? If there are multiple ways to do so, I need everything I can get on this topic.

Comment: You're not gonna get much unless you can show what you have tried thus far and why it's not working. Stack Overflow's research and code-writing services have been shut down, unfortunately.

Comment: I have no code written because I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the page on client side using ReactJS or any other framework or stack of libraries.

[How to build a Chrome Extension with React JS](https://engineering.musefind.com/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-with-react-js-e2bae31747fc)

If you want to embed some other page within your popup, then you could use `iframe` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Simple sample code to be run on your background page, this could get you started:

```
if (condition1) {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:"popup1.html"});
} else if (condition2) {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:"popup2.html"});
} else if (condition3) {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:"popup3.html"});
} // etc.
```

See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup).